# Foundation: Is using custom grid count suggested?

Tags: html, css, layout, grid, zurb-foundation

I am a back-end developer and new to Foundation as well as to CSS. I have seen few of the front-end developers generally struggles in converting a design into CSS if the designer has not considered the grid structure while designing. This generally happens because the 12 grid (default) column structure doesn't provide the flexibility to place the elements exactly as desired.

Since, Foundation provides us to use custom grid count, is it wise to use it? Most of the grid structure uses 12 grid column because 12 is a good number. What if we use a 60 grid column structure with the same gutter as we would use it for 12 grid (say gutter is 20px)? I believe it should give us more flexibility to place the elements in place.

Let me explain. Suppose we need a three column structure for my webpage, with a ratio 3:3:4 and I do not want to leave any offsets. I am not sure how can we achieve this using 12 grid columns except for may be positioning the elements manually. But in 60 grid column, we can easily achieve this by using large-18, large-18, large-24, with gutter as required, say 20px.

Some may say that if we use gutter as 20px in a 60 grid column structure, the gutters between the columns would take most of the space of the webpage. But no, gutters are imaginary till we use the actual columns. So here space for only 3 gutters will be used and rest will be the columns with the ratio 3:3:4.

This is precisely my understanding about the grid structure. Can someone with more knowledge let me know, if whatever I am assuming actually makes sense or are there some other points which I am missing and may haunt me if I use a 60 grid structure?

Answer (score 0):

Great questions.

I'm definitely no expert, but I have used Foundation quite a bit. I'll assume you're using Foundation 6. There are a couple ways you could go about accomplishing these tasks, and I've used both successfully in projects.

First way is to change the default grid to fit as many columns as you feel comfortable with maintaining. Personally, the most I've ever used is a 24 column layout. It's flexible enough to fit most layouts. Change this in your _settings.scss:

```
$grid-column-count: 24;
```

If that, generally, won't be flexible enough for you, you can use the regular grid, and also make a custom grid and call it with a class. That way, you've got the regular 12/24 column grid to use for most pages, but you can call on the custom grid for special cases. http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#grid-row

```
@include grid-row($columns, $behavior, $width, $cf, $gutter) { }
```

Lastly, if you don't want to use any of that special stuff, you can use percentages in your columns and omit the standard large-# column classes. So you custom scss would look something like this: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#columns

```
.special-column{
  @include grid-column(30%);
}
.slightly-larger-column{
  @include grid-column(40%);
}
```

Not sure if this answers all your questions, but sounds like there's just some confusion as far as best practices? You can make you grid as large as you want, but you'll have to maintain it either way.